# Datetime - String Round Trip

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, date-arithmetic, date-comparison

This gets me a string. How do I go back to a datetime object so I can do some date arithmetic and such?

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
s = datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone().isoformat()
```

This code snippet produces a string that I am happy with, but how do I get back to `datetime`?

```
2015-11-01T07:49:35.106745-08:00
```

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation, or doing any other research whatsoever?

Comment: incorporating the solution into your program is **your job**, this isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 2):

This works, but it is a lot busier than I would like to see.

```
dt = datetime.strptime(s[:-3]+s[-2:], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
print(dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert the time by using `isoformat()` before doing date arithmetic.

Try this:

```
import datetime, time

d0 = datetime.datetime.now()
time.sleep(0.1)
d1 = datetime.datetime.now()

print('trip began:{}'.format(d0.isoformat()))
print('trip ended:{}'.format(d1.isoformat()))
delta = d1 - d0
print('that took {} seconds'.format(delta.total_seconds()))
```

The above doesn't do the right thing for timezones and daylight saving time, but your original question seemed to have that part working:

`datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone()`

Sample output:

```
trip began:2015-11-01T08:52:28.326764
trip ended:2015-11-01T08:52:29.331763
that took 1.004999 seconds
```

Comment: I want to have a human-readable string as a timestamp.

Comment: @coding4fun please provide example output.

Comment: Please see my edited post. I would like to be accurate to milliseconds at least.

Comment: The timestamps will be used from different machines.

Comment: Thanks. The purpose of this exercise is to save the timestamp to a text file or a database as a human-readable string, and I do not want to save any other data besides that. So, how do I parse the string back into `datetime`?